# e-signing integration makes my multi paged pdf to single page

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, digital-signature

Am trying to sign my pdf file which is multiple paged, by fetching the signature drawn in UIView to my pdf file, but the problem I face is, after signing the pdf, i could view only the single page of file which is signed, not rest of the pages in my webview.(for eg; if page 3 of my pdf file is signed, i could view only page 3 in my webview, and the pdf file is limited to only page number 3 in my document directory).

Codes used for fetching the signature from document directory to pdf file is,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[webView reload];

UIWebView *webView;
webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 460)];

NSString *path1;
path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typo_tips" ofType:@"pdf"];

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectoryPath;
NSURL *targetURL;

documentDirectoryPath  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"typo_tips.pdf"];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:documentDirectoryPath error:&error];

NSLog(@"path1 value is %@ \n",path1);
NSLog(@"docu dir path is %@ \n",documentDirectoryPath);



if (entered==1)//"entered==1", after save button clicked in signviewcontroller 
{
   targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath];


}
else     targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];


 if (entered==1)
{


    CFURLRef url;
    url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath]);
    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
    myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

    // Create PDF context
    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL);     //(CFURLRef)outputURL
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

    int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
    NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, page));
    //"page" is current pdf page to be signed

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];// "image.png" is the saved user's signature in document directory


    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);


    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);


    // Clean up
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-render each page (even the ones not being altered).

```
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL);     //(CFURLRef)outputURL

UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < totalPages; currentPage++)
{
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, currentPage));

    //"page" is current pdf page to be signed
    if (page == currentPage)
    {
         NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];// "image.png" is the saved user's signature in document directory
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);
    }
}
// Clean up
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

Comment: ya, I have tried the same with the for loop, and it results in displaying the whole pdf's content as a single page (eg: page 1 to 5 content is displayed as single page) and the signature is integrated at respective position.

Comment: can u suggest me, regarding displaying as a single page of pdf.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with the help of iPDFDev:

In the for loop have to create a new PDF page for each page in the source file. So move these lines inside the for loop:

```
 CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
```

and also the corresponding cleanup code.

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[webView reload];

UIWebView *webView;
webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 460)];

NSString *path1;
path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typo_tips" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectoryPath;
NSURL *targetURL;

documentDirectoryPath  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"typo_tips.pdf"];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:documentDirectoryPath error:&error];

NSLog(@"path1 value is %@ \n",path1);
NSLog(@"docu dir path is %@ \n",documentDirectoryPath);



if (entered==1)//"entered==1", after save button clicked in signviewcontroller 
{
targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath];


}
else     targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];


 if (entered==1)
{


CFURLRef url;
url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath]);
CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

// Create PDF context
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL);     

int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < totalPages; currentPage++)
{

//(CFURLRef)outputURL
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, page));
//"page" is current pdf page to be signed

    if (page == currentPage)
    {

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];// "image.png" is the saved user's signature in document directory

    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);
    }

// Clean up
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
}
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```